# Content Doesn't fit the ScrollPane. Can't Scroll until End

Tags: java, javafx

I'm trying to fit my Content to my scrollPane. However, I cannot scroll until the end of the content. It work if resize the whole pane to my PC screen (1920,1080), however it can't fit for my laptop resolution (1366,768).
This is what happen

```
///////////////////////////////////////////////////CENTER SIDE OF THE PANE///////////////////////////////////////////////////
//Scroll Pane for insert centerbox in it
ScrollPane scroll = new ScrollPane();


//Grid pane for center box
GridPane centerbox= new GridPane();
centerbox.setHgap(15);
centerbox.setVgap(30);




//Input picture
javafx.scene.image.Image img = new     
javafx.scene.image.Image(getClass().getResource("arcade.jpg").toExternalForm());
ImageView imgv1 = new ImageView(img);
imgv1.setFitHeight(150);
imgv1.setFitWidth(150);
imgv1.setVisible(true);

Image img2 = new Image(getClass().getResource("Bowling.jpg").toExternalForm());
ImageView imgv2 = new ImageView(img2);
imgv2.setFitHeight(150);
imgv2.setFitWidth(150);
imgv2.setVisible(true);

Image img3 = new Image(getClass().getResource("cc.jpg").toExternalForm());
ImageView imgv3 = new ImageView(img3);
imgv3.setFitHeight(150);
imgv3.setFitWidth(150);
imgv3.setVisible(true);

Image img4 = new Image(getClass().getResource("circus.jpg").toExternalForm());
ImageView imgv4 = new ImageView(img4);
imgv4.setFitHeight(150);
imgv4.setFitWidth(150);
imgv4.setVisible(true);

Image img5= new Image(getClass().getResource("karaoke.jpg").toExternalForm());
ImageView imgv5 = new ImageView(img5);
imgv5.setFitHeight(150);
imgv5.setFitWidth(150);
imgv5.setVisible(true);

Image img6= new Image(getClass().getResource("kidzania.jpg").toExternalForm());
ImageView imgv6 = new ImageView(img6);
imgv6.setFitHeight(150);
imgv6.setFitWidth(150);
imgv6.setVisible(true);

Image img7= new Image(getClass().getResource("skatepark.jpg").toExternalForm());
ImageView imgv7 = new ImageView(img7);
imgv7.setFitHeight(150);
imgv7.setFitWidth(150);
imgv7.setVisible(true);






//////////////////////////////////////////////COMBINING ALL THE PANE TOGETHER////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


//Place Node on Pane(1)
centerbox.add(imgv1,0,0);
Button buy = new Button("Reserve");
Label l1 = new Label();
l1.setText("'Arcade-ium'\n\n\nAt Arcade-ium, you can enjoy a lot of classic and modern arcade game.\nWe assure you your satisfaction");
l1.setFont(Font.font("Helvetica",FontWeight.BOLD,20));
centerbox.add(buy,2,0);
centerbox.add(l1,1,0);


//Event Handler to change scene to reservepage
buy.setOnAction(e->{
    Stage stg = (Stage)buy.getScene().getWindow();
    stg.setScene(rp.getScene1());
});




 ///Repeat until 7 node
//Place Node on Pane(7)
centerbox.add(imgv7,0,6);
Button buy6 = new Button("Reserve");
Label l7 = new Label();
l7.setText("'xTremePark'\n\nxTremePark was built in 2011. We have a lot of facilities here to facilitate our youngster who\nlove to take the risk and go beyond.");
l7.setFont((Font.font("helvetica",FontWeight.BOLD,20)));
centerbox.add(l7,1,6);
centerbox.add(buy6,2,6);

//Event Handler to change scene to reservepage
buy6.setOnAction(e->{
    Stage stg = (Stage)buy6.getScene().getWindow();
    stg.setScene(rp.getScene7());
});


//Formatting the pane
scroll.setContent(centerbox);

//Im using borderpane for the whole scene. And Im going to insert the scrollpane into the center.
```

I cannot seem to scroll until the end my content when i run the program. I tried to use .setMinHeight() and .setPrefHeight().

but nothings work. So is there any way for me to set how much the scroller would scroll in my scrollpane?
[Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f0s02.png)

Comment: Please no links to code. All code must be in your question itself as code-formatted text.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I'm sorry. Done editing the code